# combine two pieces of data in R

Tags: r, list, vector, concatenation

i'm not sure how to best describe this, so i'll just show you.  i have two variables.
A:

```
              ID
1             121
2             122
3             123
4             124
5             125
6             126
7             127
8             128
9             129
```

and B:

```
       var1     var2       var3 
1      57.1     116.5      73.0
2      38.1      15.8      22.7
3      84.2      99.2      72.2
```

and i would like them to end up as such:

```
              ID
1             121   57.1
2             122   116.5
3             123   73.0
4             124   38.1
5             125   15.8
6             126   22.7
7             127   84.2
8             128   99.2
9             129   72.2
```

does that make sense?  i'd like to maintain the original variable and add a column that is the rows, in order, of the other variable.  preferably i'd like this as a data frame.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show the result of `dput(A)` and `dput(B)` to make the example reproducible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

data.frames and matrices are filled `by column` by default, as you want create a numeric vector filling by row, you will need to transpose the data.frame before coercing to a numeric variable, so it will be in the order you want.

```
A$value <- c(t(B))
```

transposing a `data.frame` gives a matrix, which is coerced to a numeric vector by `c`.

Comment: +1. That is a really, really neat solution. Here I was about to post a solution using `melt`

Comment: thanks, i always appreciate a good explanation to go with an answer.  what is 'value' in your example?  is it the name of the column of A or the name of the new column that i will be adding to A?

Comment: @user1714887 It is the name of the column in `A` that  will contain the values (if it already existed, it would be overwritten with these new values)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `B` is a `data.frame`, you can do:

```
cbind(A,var.name=as.vector(as.matrix(B)))
```

You can pass the new column name instead of `var.name`

Comment: this also worked.  however i don't know enough about programming to know which is the "better" answer. thank you as well.

Comment: Both are OK, just I feel this solution is more explicit/readable but it is just my opinion.